# What are usages similar to "Need I say more?"?

Tags: phrases, word-usage, modal-verbs, do-support

I recall hearing usages like

> Need I say more?
>   Need I remind you that ...?

instead of

> Do I need to say more?
>   Do I need to remind you that ...?

Indeed, they sound better, at least to me. I wonder whether there are more usages like this or not. Is this special to the verb *need* or are there similar usages like these?

Comment: They don't sound better. In some cases they might be less emphatic, perhaps, less insistent—but not always.

Comment: *Have* behaves similarly in certain dialects. As in, "Have you a car?" and such.

Comment: [_Noodge, noodge; wink, wink. Say no more. Know what I mean?_](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ona-RhLfRfc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verbs *need* and *dare* are sometimes called "semi-modal", in that they sometimes behave like modal verbs (eg *can*:  forming their negative and interrogative without *do*, and not taking *-s* in the third person singular).

The degree to which they do so varies between speakers, and according to register (degree of formality).

The idioms you mention ("*Need I say more*" etc.) are widespread.

In Britain *I/you/he need not* and *I/you/he dare not* are common, but I believe they are less common in American English.

"Need you", as in *Need you go so soon?* is old fashioned in Britain, but is still heard; I don't know about America.